# auto-code <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6"></div> by emmet

Tags: html, emmet

How can I do auto-code the workd that has brank `<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6"></div>` using emmet?
When I typed

`.col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6`,

it returned

`.col-sm-offset-3 <col-sm-6></col-sm-6>` .

Comment: You need a `.` before each class; `.one.two`.

Comment: Get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing, I've got it.
`.col-sm-offset-3.col-sm-6`